Copying files from NAS to SD card creates corrupted files
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I have tried to copy 8 to 12 GB of mp3 files from my Synology 212 NAS to a micro SD card via a cabled network. Usually I use Nautilus to copy the files. But I always end up with corrupted files.
If I try to play the music, a lot of files contain glitches in the sound. But the last time, I even discovered songs with several seconds of music from song A in the file of song B! How is this possible?!
I have tried several cards (and brands) and I have used several micro SD adapters (both 'micro-SD to SD card' and USB adapters). I always use the same machine: a Zotac ZBOX Nano AQ01 (AMD A4-5000) with 8 GB RAM. I am trying to copy files for a few years now, but I never managed to put my finger on it. So I diverted to a Windows laptop of a housemate and then I do not get any corrupted mp3-files. I know the Zotac is not the most powerful PC but copying an array of bytes should not be that difficult?
I understand that somewhere between my NAS and my Ubuntu-PC, some data could get corrupted, but isn't there some verify mechanism during the copy process? And how do complete blocks of data, even end up in the wrong file?

More details are needed to offer any help. Please use edit and add to the question the version of Ubuntu and the exact steps you are doing to copy the files.

Try copying the files one at a time with Midnight Commander.

@David This isn't an acute problem, it is more chronicle: I am trying this once in a while for years. The machine is from 2014. So it might have been happening maybe since Ubuntu 14.04. At the moment I still have 20.04.6. I cannot remember that copying the files was stable, so which Ubuntu version is not that important, I think. I don't think there is some kind of bug in the OS. The failure is probably somewhere in my network, but obviously there is just no verifying mechanism in the copy command?

@kyodake That is a good suggestion. I will try mc next time.
